# using join to get records of a specific fk

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table of ParentsSchoolContact, which a parentId have foreign key to the parentId:

```
CREATE TABLE ParentsSchoolContact (
  contactId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  parentId int NOT NULL,
  name varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  age varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (contactId),
  FOREIGN KEY (parentId) REFERENCES Parent(parentId)
);
```

and I have a parent and contact table that keeps the relation between a kid and a parent:

```
CREATE TABLE ParentAndContact (
  parentId int NOT NULL,
  contactId int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (contactId, parentId)
);
```

I want to get all the contacts related to a specific parent that i have its id, would that be the right query?

```
SELECT c.name, c.age
FROM ParentsSchoolContact c 
INNER JOIN ParentAndKid pc ON pc.contactId = c.contactId 
    AND c.parentId = myParentVariable 
    AND pc.parentId = myParentVariable
```

wanted to make sure this query dosent fall in some case you could think about :)

thanks!

Comment: Do you want to include parents with no kids? Or kids with no parents?

Comment: You don't need this part: 'k.parentId = myParentVariable AND'.

Comment: If your `myParentVariable` is your `parentID`, then you don't need to reference `ParentAndKid`, just use `WHERE k.parentID = myParentVariable`.

Comment: @Shawn no, im only selecting the kids, so i want only the kids of a specific parent

Comment: @MNY Either your `Kid` table doesn't need a `parentID`, or you don't need the `ParentAndKid` table. My choice would be to keep `ParentAndKid` and drop `Kid.parentID`. Then you would just drop `AND pk.parentID = myParentVariable` from your query.

Answer (score 0):

For me, i see that the ParentAndContact table is redundant. Usually the Parents details are in one table and ContactID/Kids details are in another table (having attributes eg. courses which the kids enrolled, details of the kids).

Assuming that you want to get **all the contacts related to a specific parent that you have its id from the available tables (ParentsSchoolContact,ParentAndContact)**, *You can just write a simple query to retrieve the information from ParentsSchoolContact table as of below*:-

```
select contactId, parentId, name, age 
from ParentsSchoolContact
where parentId = myParentVariable
```

Do let me know if i miss out anything.